# PHP MySQL Disable a button if today is Sunday

Tags: php, html

Need some help on how to disable a button. Using HTML/PHP

If today is Sunday, disable the button.

```
<button>Disable Me</button>
```

Else If today is Weekdays, (from 8am to 5pm) the button is active. Otherwise, the button is disabled.

```
if(8am to 5pm){

<button>Active</button>

}else{
<button>Disable Me</button>
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Comment: wow thanks. i think i know how to code the 1st. But on the second, i think its quite complicated and i think my mind will explode..hehe.. can someone show an example of codes? Thanks much appreciated :D

Comment: Manipulating dates ain't the easiest thing to do, but dig on google, I m sure you will find examples

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$current_date_array = getdate();

if($current_date_array['weekday'] == "Sunday" || $current_date_array['hours'] < 8 || $current_date_array['hours'] > 17){
    //disable the button
} else {
    //enable
}
```

This means

if(today is Sunday OR time less than 8 am OR time is greater than 5 pm))